# Does your wifi router mess up your melatonin which messes up your sleep?

Tags: sleep

From https://www.kitguru.net/channel/generaltech/larry-alton/3-reasons-to-upgrade-your-network-with-cat6a-ethernet-cables/

> If you’re one of thousands of people who suffer from EMF sensitivity,
>   the ability to get rid of your wireless router is one of the best
>   reasons to embrace Cat6a cables.
>
> You don’t really need Wi-Fi; with the right equipment, you can setup
>   an Ethernet cable in every room you’ll work from. In addition to
>   discouraging you from working on the couch, you’ll probably experience
>   **better sleep without your wireless router**. **That’s because melatonin –
>   the substance that contributes to a good night’s sleep – is inhibited
>   by the presence of electrosmog**.
>
> According to Dr. Mercola, many people with high sensitivity have a
>   high amount of **heavy metals** in their system. “If you have accumulated
>   toxic metals in your brain, your brain becomes like an antenna,
>   picking up more cell phone radiation, which in turn can cause the
>   microbes in your system to overreact and create more potent
>   mycotoxins,” Dr. Mercola states. “This can create a never-ending
>   vicious cycle between the microbes and metals in your body and your
>   exposure to electromagnetic fields, which can lead to
>   hypersensitivity.”

Do heavy metals cause your brain to function like an antenna?
Does electrosmog inhibit melatonin?
Does melatonin help sleeping (or the lack thereof, inhibit sleeping?)

Comment: See the previous questions here on EMF sensitivity ...  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=EMF+sensitivity  While you are at it, the previous questions on Dr Mercola https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mercola

Comment: My guess, third question: yes melatonin helps sleep; the other two questions: no.

Comment: Do they advocate getting rid of cell phones too? Those are potentially higher-power and almost always closer to you.